# HTML Shuffle div images javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I shuffle these images in result.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/87/e9/38/87e938ab69a614cddb14a6866b2478d0.jpg" onclick="app();" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/564x/32/03/4f/32034f6da33f2932d88c6d6db7fa117a.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/96/e6/54/96e654398c4b2cd7afc03410d636dbea.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/4e/78/48/4e7848375fa721845f4986006229555a.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/1a/b0/d4/1ab0d4ef04e3e789396ae744f626c68a.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/41/fd/31/41fd312937d0fd0e864d8fdd53f055ba.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/06/98/94/069894936419220407b4b11edfca833d.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <img src="https://i-h1.pinimg.com/736x/18/8b/bf/188bbfa47af6b445cf2a5a1869c90566.jpg" style="width:100%">

  </div>  
</div>
```

How can I use js to shuffle these images. Each time different images hould be on top.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question and include the relevant `javascript` that you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="deck">
  <div><img src="" /></div>
  <div><img src="" /></div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>


// jQuery specific:
// 1) remove elements from DOM and convert them into a native JavaScript array
// 2) apply algorithm
// 3) inject the array back to DOM

var a = $("#deck > div").remove().toArray();
for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var bi = a[i];
    var bj = a[j];
    a[i] = bj;
    a[j] = bi;
}
$("#deck").append(a);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2m9tsubg/1/)

Comment: Although I think you have posted a good answer but this doesn't really match the expected output *"Each time different images should be on top"*. It doesn't help that the relevant source code hasn't been provided but *"be on top"* is much different to *"be above"* Also the first image has a onclick event to call `app();` which I can only assume should be used to shuffle the images again.